# GCal: quick add event specifying duration and time zone

Tags: google-calendar

Let's say you want to book flight BAW182 in your calendar, which departs at 10:55PM EDT and arrives at 10:07AM BST (+1). What's the correct syntax for quickly adding the event? I can't get Google Calendar to recognize the end of the event. (I have this problem even if both start and end are in the same time zone.)

Neither works:

```
Flight BAW182 at 10:55PM EDT - 10:07AM BST
Flight BAW182 at 10:55PM EDT-10:07AM BST
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Durations with Quick Add aren't very precise. The best I've been able to find is to include "for {duration}" with the entry, where duration is for hours or minutes. So, in your case, something like:

```
Flight BAW182 at 10:55PM EDT for 8 hours
```

Unfortunately, while I can get it to create entries with a different duration than my default, it's really very basic. For instance, all of these *failed*:

```
Flight BAW182 at 10:55PM EDT for 8.5 hours
Flight BAW182 at 10:55PM EDT for 8 hours 40 minutes
Flight BAW182 at 10:55PM EDT for 8:40
Flight BAW182 at 10:55PM EDT for 8:40 hours
```

I don't see a way to add an end time, either. All of these *failed*:

```
Flight BAW182 at 10:55PM EDT until 10:07AM BST
Flight BAW182 at 10:55PM EDT to 10:07AM BST
Flight BAW182 at 10:55PM EDT end 10:07AM BST
```

Quick Add really seems to be for very basic calendar adds. Anything that gets outside of "something at some time on some day" just doesn't work that well.

(The information in [Google Calendar support](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/72143) isn't particularly helpful, and certainly not in this regard.)